# Create field of Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I am using below code to create Custom Post Types.

```
$supports = array(
                    'title', // post title
                    'editor', // post content
                    'author', // post author
                    'thumbnail', // featured images
                    'excerpt', // post excerpt
                    'custom-fields', // custom fields
                    'comments', // post comments
                    'revisions', // post revisions
                    'post-formats', // post formats
                );

                $labels = array(
                    'name' => _x('news', 'plural'),
                    'singular_name' => _x('news', 'singular'),
                    'menu_name' => _x('news', 'admin menu'),
                    'name_admin_bar' => _x('news', 'admin bar'),
                    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'add new'),
                    'add_new_item' => __('Add New news'),
                    'new_item' => __('New news'),
                    'edit_item' => __('Edit news'),
                    'view_item' => __('View news'),
                    'all_items' => __('All news'),
                    'search_items' => __('Search news'),
                    'not_found' => __('No news found.'),
                );

                $args = array(
                    'supports' => $supports,
                    'labels' => $labels,
                    'public' => true,
                    'query_var' => true,
                    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news'),
                    'has_archive' => true,
                    'hierarchical' => false,
                );
                register_post_type('news', $args);
```

I am getting below Form at the time of Custom Post entry.

[image]

How can I add another Text field after `Title` named `Name` ?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the classic editor, you can add new input fields to the editing view by creating custom metaboxes. This is done with `add_meta_box()`. Check out [the code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) for further details and good examples on how to register a metabox, and how to save and edit post meta with it.

*Although I can't quite remember, if it is possible to have the metabox between the title and editor fields.*